# Omitir beginTransaction commit PDO MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

O que acontece na prática quando eu omito o `begin transaction` e o `commit` em um script PHP usando PDO?

Tenho um script de carga, que processa os dados de escolas, a cada escola que termina o processamento faço um `insert`. Esse código abaixo fica dentro de um laço que percorre uma lista gigantesca de escolas.
Nesse caso que não inseri o `begintran` e o `commit`. Ele comita de forma auto depois de cada inserção?

```
$insere = $pdo->prepare("Insert INTO `tabela`(campo1,campo2,campo3) VALUES (:valor1,:valor2,:valor3)");
        $insere->bindValue(":valor1", $dado1);
        $insere->bindValue(":valor2", $dado2);
        $insere->bindValue(":valor3", $dado3);
        $insere->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Sim

No caso de banco de dados que seguem o modelo ACID, na ausência de transações então cada instrução acaba tendo uma transação implícita automática. Basicamente é `autocommit` a cada instrução. [E o MySQL segue esse modelo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-acid.html).

Nesse caso particular esteja preparado para lidar com falhas. Se der algum erro no processamento dessa lista "gigantesca", então uma nova rodada do script talvez não funcione (INSERTs falharem por duplicação de chave primária).